# MVC creating a grid of Pills (one for each row in a database)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating a view which needs a dashboard showing the status of vehicles.
I would like to have a pill for each vehicle in the database, the colour of the pill will indicate the status of the vehicle (i.e. good, fair, bad) and the text of the pill will be the vehicle key number.

I want to have the pills laid out in a grid fashion to maximise the space available.  The number of rows (vehicles) in the database is not known but is usually between 40 and 50.

I am using MVC5 with EF6 and fairly inexperienced in web development.  Any thoughts on the best way to achieve this?  a link to any examples or tutorials would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Html Helper which takes in the status id. In Helpers\Exetensions.cs;

```
namespace StackOverflowWQuestion.Helpers
{
 public static class MyHTMLHelpers
 {
      public static string PillHelper(this HtmlHelper helper, int statusId)
      {
          string htmlString = "";
          switch (caseSwitch)
          {
           case 1:
               htmlString = "<img src="pill-good.png" /> ;
               break;
           case 2:
               htmlString = "<img src="pill-bad.png" /> ;
               break;
         default:
               htmlString = "<img src="pill-fair.png" /> ;
               break;
          }

          return htmlString;
      }
}
```

}

You can use it in views like this:

```
@Html.PillHelper(Model.StatusId)
```

I'm assuming you have a value in your data called StatusId which is a foreign key into a Status Table.

Tutorial here using old view engine; If you just google asp.net mvc html helper tutorial you will find lots of results.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: Thanks that's set me on the right path. The other part that has me scratching my head is the layout in the view.  I want to have a layout that puts the pills or badges into a grid or multi column list.  Problem is I don't know how many there will be at design time. any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you use a table? Create a table heading row then loop through each car in the model to add each row. I would recommend you go through the beginner tutorials here http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started